# Disable using the desktop.ini file

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, desktop.ini

How can I disable Windows Explorer in Windows XP from using `desktop.ini` and `folder.ini` files?

Some viruses are on the flash card, and they can be in those files. Can I make Windows Explorer safe from opening such flash card?

Autorun is disabled.

Yes, there are other file managers, but it is my girlfriend's computer.

Comment: This is the first time I hear of `desktop.ini` being used for virus activation.

Comment: may be i misconfise with folder.htt ?

Comment: You're confusing desktop.ini with autorun.inf, I think.

Comment: @Randolph Potter, no. autorun.inf is disabled. There is other way to do an virus infection while opening a removable disk in the explorer. Some time ago, ~8 years, folder.htt was used for this by real viruses. It was an interactive customized look of the folder, like for System folder on Programm files. This look is coded as HTML and it is runned by Explorer when visiting folder.

Comment: @osgx: I'm quite sure `folder.htt` does not work in Windows XP, and _that_ is 8 years old. It won't work in later versions of Windows either.

Comment: Autorun may be disabled on your system, but I've seen Conficker infect a machine that has Autorun disabled, just by inserting the flash drive. Anyway, I still think your question is unlikely to be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use advice from [Disabling Folder.htt and Desktop.ini in Registry](http://computertipstricks.blogspot.com/2005/04/disabling-folderhtt-and-desktopini-in.html) page:

> To let you know, desktop.ini and folder.htt are both important files in Windows system. But they were already infected with malicious codes, we can disable the use of it, anyway, Windows will still works fine without this two files.